# Div not hiding after bool for hidden property changes nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a bool called isStarted that is initially set to false.

I have two divs, one that has:

```
hidden={isVisible}
```

and the other has:

```
hidden={!isVisible}
```

I have a href link that has a onclick that calls a function which changes the bool value to it's inverse value. I confirm this by also console.logging the bools value. Each time I click it the value changes.

However the the divs do not change visibility, it just keeps showing the first one.

**div1:**

```
            <div
              className="relative"
              hidden={isVisible}
            > div1 </>
```

**div2:**

```
           <div
              className="relative"
              hidden={!isVisible}
            > div 2 </>
```

I also confirmed these divs show independently by manually setting the isVisible to true and false at the start.

EDIT:

This way works to change the visibility also, but only works the first time when the app goes live:

```
{isVisible && <div>wow</div>}
```

However when I click and change the isVisible value it still won't change the divs.

Answer (score 3):

The `hidden` HTML attribute does not exist. You might be looking for the `display` CSS attribute.

```
<div style={{ display: none }} />
```

Offtopic personal suggestion: I'd suggest you starting learning React using TypeScript from the beginning. TS will warn you when an attribute does not exist and help you on your learning path.

EDIT:

It is `display: none` (removes the element) or `visibility: hidden` (hides but still takes space. I might have been on drugs when writing this.

Comment: thank you, can you explain why its {{hidden: true}} and not {hidden: true}. Why the dual brackets?

Comment: Type '{ hidden: true; }' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'hidden' does not exist in type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'

Comment: you may be missing the react type definitions (@types/react)? When you hover over style it should say it has type React.CSSProperties.
When you rename a file to TS next.js will suggest you to install some packages on console.
You may need to F1 + restart TS server on VS Code after installing packages (usually you dont).
About the dual brackets: { hidden: true } is a regular object. The style prop accepts an object with CSS properties, but their names are camelCased. Ex: border-top becomes borderTop.

Comment: Fixed the response